# Making a XHR Request in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, xmlhttprequest, network-programming

I'm using DroidCamX to stream my phone's cam to a C# app, works easy. Now I have to enable the camera flashlight from inside my app (important), which usually you would do via the web interface by going to *localip*:4747 and clicking a button. I have zero knowledge regarding network communication, so I don't even know where to start.

The only thing I could find out is that when I go to the Network Tab in chrome and click the flash button on the page, it shows something named "led_toggle" of type "xhr" with Initiator "jquery.min.js:5", apparently that thing only exists in JavaScript, is there any way to do it with C#?

Answer (score 1):

XHR is just the handle/API used by Browsers to do a https network call. Here the prototype https is what you must be concerned about not XHR as it is just the API the browser provides. In fact XHR stands for XMLHttpRequest. In C# you can use http packages already available to do the same network call. Here is the link that provides the API to make network call from C#
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the information already! Can you help me with finding out which calls I need to make in my app? I mean I only have that button as a clue and I don't know how to find out which calls my browser is doing so I can replicate them

Comment: Update: Nevermind, I found out that you can rightclick an entry in the chrome Network thingy and copy stuff about it

Comment: Yes thats right. You will find all Network calls/Cache/JS Files in the developer options.